# Compare strings

Tags: text-processing, join

I have 2 txt files, in one i have alias lists and the other is the servers name. So what im trying to do is to loop from the alias txt file line by line and where it will find the name that is on the other txt file ( servers name ) will be echo or writhe in other file. For example:
In this alias.txt file we have something like this

```
alias server1='ssh root@server1.com'
alias server2='ssh root@server2.com'
alias server3='ssh root@server3.com'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

and in the other file we have just:

```
server1
server2
server3
```

Now when i list the alias.txt i like to compear the other txt files with the alias names and to gave me just the alias value. If he find server1 write to file or echo ssh root@server1.com ...

The main point is I have many alias that are like server1 ( ssh connections ) but i like some servers not all of them and i need just specific ones ( in this example the ones that i have in the server.txt file )

Any hints ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?:

```
$ grep -F -f serverlist.txt alias.txt 
alias server1='ssh root@server1.com'
alias server2='ssh root@server2.com'
alias server3='ssh root@server3.com'
```

It uses the lines of the `serverlist.txt` as patterns to match for showing lines form `alias.txt`. Depending on the names of your servers, it may need to be a little more complicated to not give wrong matches, like if a server is named just `server`.

It would be much more safe to first convert the plain server names to patterns only matching the left side of the alias definition:

```
$ sed "s/\(.*\)/^alias \1='/" serverlist.txt                      
^alias server1='
^alias server2='
^alias server3='
```

We can use `-f -` to read the patterns from stdin, just like we did directly from the file before:

```
$ sed "s/\(.*\)/^alias \1='/" serverlist.txt | grep -f - alias.txt
alias server1='ssh root@server1.com'
alias server2='ssh root@server2.com'
alias server3='ssh root@server3.com'
```

Comment: Dude This is GREAT ! THIS is what i need ( the first one grep -F -f ) i didn't know about this options in grep. Thanks a loot ...

Comment: My pleasure! - I was surprised myself how short and clear it was :)